# MySQL Update Query with last update state

Tags: mysql, sql

I needs SQL query, that it should select the last updated state with time and then update the last column value with new value I will provide in query.
Example, here I am updating for 3 md (column name)

[image]

```
update table1 set sta=5 where sta=4 and tgn=9020 and md=84414469;
update table1 set sta=4 where sta=3 and tgn=2602 and md=68028162;
update table1 set sta=3 where sta=9 and tgn=319 and md=84215297;
```

for more details:
1st query will select last sta number like 3,4 and then will update with the new sta number.
my purpose is to update the sta column value but only that value which will be founds as last update.

Comment: What's the question? And why does 319 go to 43 when the others 2 seem to increment by 1?

Comment: I want to update last state with last update time I founds.

Comment: Last state = most recent date by tgn and md? and are you manually providing the new sta?

Comment: Add a proper description of what you want to do and what the requirements are for selecting a particular row to be updated, I have tried to figure out a logic for what you want to do but I have failed. Add this to your question and not as a comment.

Comment: question description updated.

Comment: @P.Salmon yesnew data with new sta number manal I have .

Answer (score 1):

Join the table with a query that gets the highest `sta` for each group:

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1
JOIN (SELECT tgn, md, MAX(sta) AS max_sta
      FROM table1
      WHERE md IN (84414469, 68028162, 84215297)
      GROUP BY tgn, md) AS t2
ON t1.tgn = t2.tgn AND t1.md = t2.md AND t1.sta = t2.max_sta
JOIN other_table AS t3 ON t3.tgn = t1.tgn AND t3.md = t1.md
SET t1.sta = t3.sta
```

Comment: Thank you, but sta+1 , here I have different number, some time from 5 to 9 and 8 to 4 or 3 like this I have to update.
and I have manul data for the new update

Comment: Where does the new value come from?

Comment: I have taken from another DB and its in excel sheet. @Barmar

Comment: You can join with the other table. If you show the table in the question, I'll update the answer.

Comment: ok, this is good idea, I will create table for the other data and will join, 
example, other table will have data like this column,

tgn,md,sta

tgn and md will be same for both tables. @Barmar

Comment: and also query should update only for the given md and state from table 1

Comment: You can use a `WHERE` clause for that.

Comment: I've added the join to my answer.

Comment: please if you can share query with two md updated as in where clasue

Comment: I added that to the answer.